# How to call multiple passport-jwt strategies in the same app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm able to differentiate the two routes and 
authenticate the first route(student). When i call the second route(teacher) to be authenticated, a empty JSON file is returned.

In users.js 'passportStudent.authenticate' works and returns a JSON file with user information as intended, But i'm not sure why 'passportTeacher.authenticate' returns a empty JSON file.

Here's My Code:

users.js:

```
const passportStudent = require('passport');
const passportTeacher = require('passport');

/*Some code here*/

router.get('/profile/student', passportStudent.authenticate('student', {session: false}), (req, res, next) =>{
    res.json({user : req.user});
});

router.get('/profile/teacher', passportTeacher.authenticate('teacher', {session: false}), (req, res, next) =>{
    res.json({teacher : req.teacher});
});
```

passport.js:

```
    const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
    const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
    const User = require('../models/user');
    const Teacher = require('../models/teacher');
    const config = require('../config/database');

    module.exports = function(passport){
        let opts = {};
        opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
        opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
        passport.use('student', new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done)  => {
            console.log(jwt_payload);
            User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id, (err, user) => {
                if(err){
                    return done(err, false);
                }
                if(user){
                    return done(null, user);
                }
                else{
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });
        }));

        passport.use('teacher', new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload2, done)  => {
            console.log(jwt_payload2);
            Teacher.getTeacherById(jwt_payload2.data._id, (err, teacher) => {
                if(err){
                    return done(err, false);
                }
                if(teacher){
                    return done(null, teacher);
                }
                else{
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });
        }));
    }
```

app.js code for Passport:

```
const passportStudent = require('passport');
const passportTeacher = require('passport');

/*Some code here*/

app.use(passportStudent.initialize());
app.use(passportStudent.session());

app.use(passportTeacher.initialize());
app.use(passportTeacher.session());

require('./config/passport')(passportStudent);
require('./config/passport')(passportTeacher);
```

How can I authenticate either on desired routes? Or should I go for local strategy for student and jwt for teacher?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the following link could help https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the passport store the signed users information in `req.user`.

So you need to update the teacher router to

```
router.get('/profile/teacher', passportTeacher.authenticate('teacher', {session: false}), (req, res, next) =>{
    res.json({teacher : req.user});
});
```

Here I change

```
res.json({teacher : req.teacher});
```

To

```
res.json({teacher : req.user});
```